# Why does the function return each element of the list on a new line?

Tags: python, list, append

So i have this code right here to separate only ints or floats out of a file and add them to a list, however when it returns the list, it returns each element on a new line and not the entire list on the same line, and I'm wondering why?
the list looks kind of like this:
12 w 21 d23g780nb deed e2 21.87
43 91 - . 222 mftg 21 bx .1 3 g d e 6 de ddd32 3412

```
def read_numbers(path: str) -> list:
    with open(path) as f:
        file_elem = f.read().split()
    a = []
    for x in file_elem:
        if x.isnumeric():
            a.append(int(x))
        elif "." in x:
            b = x.replace(".","")
            if b.isnumeric():
                a.append(float(x))
    return a
```

If I remove the looking for floats part it will only add the ints to the list but it will return the list as intended,
Out[101]: [12, 21, 43, 91, 222, 21, 3, 6, 3412, 0, 0, 0, 1, 70, 12, 1, 9, 445, 100]
however when adding the floats, it seems that the entire list gets messed up like this
[image]

and i'm wondering why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file like this:

file **a**:

```
12 43 12.145 546 23 76 5.54 231.1 32
```

then I run your code like this:

```py
In [3]: def read_numbers(path: str) -> list:
   ...:     with open(path) as f:
   ...:         file_elem = f.read().split()
   ...:     a = []
   ...:     for x in file_elem:
   ...:         if x.isnumeric():
   ...:             a.append(int(x))
   ...:         elif "." in x:
   ...:             b = x.replace(".","")
   ...:             if b.isnumeric():
   ...:                 a.append(float(x))
   ...:     return a
   ...:

In [4]: read_numbers('./a')
Out[4]: [12, 43, 12.145, 546, 23, 76, 5.54, 231.1, 32]
```

And so everything is OK.

---

UPDATE:

I changed file like this:

new file a:

```
12 43 12.145 546 23 76 5.54 231.1 32
ad
adfad ga 235 1.12
adf a1 12 si
124 sd  1.12
```

and so output is like this:

```py
In [5]: read_numbers('./a')
Out[5]: [12, 43, 12.145, 546, 23, 76, 5.54, 231.1, 32, 235, 1.12, 12, 124, 1.12]
```

Comment: Try adding some new lines to your file, some chars, sybols, etc. the idea is sorting the ints and floats out of a lot of garbage from the file, the file is meant to be very messy.

Comment: Yea thanks, for the update, i'd try to share an image but it won't let me... i dont get what's happening, it makes no sense... I thought i might be dumb not understanding something, it feels like its a random thing... but i know it's not...

Comment: @Bubu Maybe IPython shows it as a column so it is IPython responsibility, do you check it on pure python interpreter?

Comment: Yea I just did, the output is normal, I just dont get why pycharm displays it in this weird way when adding the floats to it, and displays it normally when just adding the ints, this is quite weird.